# How to make a search on google maps for finding hospitals etc

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I want to make google map where we can search a hospitals , police station etc on the base of current location. But as per the  google search i knew that past all Google places api's are deprecated. so i used https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup 
Using this link for crating google places api key,But its not working for me its not getting any data ...

I am referring this link i used to change only api key here
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Its not working not getting any data & when i put my google search api path its shown that is not valid api .

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker i m referring this link also but i m not able to find proper solution. Please let me know if any one is having any idea??

Answer (score 1):

Refer this tutorials [Google Places API](https://androiddhoom.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api/)

Make Sure you done following steps right.

**1. Get the API key for Google Maps Android API V2**

We need to get an API key from Google to use Google Maps in Android application.

Please follow the given below link to get the API key for Google Maps Android API v2.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

**2. Get the API key for Google Places API**

We can create API key for Google Place API by clicking “Create new Browser key”  available at the “API Access” pane of the Google console URL : http://code.google.com/apis/console.

Also ensure that, “Places API” is enabled in the “Services” pane of the Google console.

**3. Add Android Support library to this project**

By default, Android support library (android-support-v4.jar ) is added to this project by Eclipse IDE to the directory libs. If it is not added, we can do it manually by doing the following steps :

Open Project Explorer by Clicking “Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer”
Right click this project
Then from popup menu, Click “Android Tools -> Add Support Library “

Downlod The Full Source Code From [Github](https://github.com/sandeeplondhe/GooglePlaces).

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario there is Two keys required and 3 permission when you are going for Near By Places Integration --

1-Android Key

2-Browser Key

**Permission on Google Console--**

1-Google Maps Android API

2-Google Places API for Android

3-Google Places API Web Service

Hope this will help you.

Thanks