# Save Markers on Android Map App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am creating an Android Map App where I want to create marker at my current location and also display previous such markers. I am able to create marker at my current location but when I resume the app at a different location, my app is only showing current location marker not the previous ones. Please help. Here is what I tried:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public Location mLastLocation;
ArrayList<LatLng> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<>();
public boolean isMapReady = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    }
}


public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    isMapReady = true;
}

public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    return false;
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);

    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.position(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

    mp.title("my position");

    mMap.addMarker(mp);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 16));
    LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    listOfPoints.add(newLatLng);


   }

public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        // Modes: MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE
        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("latlngpoints.txt",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(output);
        dout.writeInt(listOfPoints.size()); // Save line count
        for (LatLng point : listOfPoints) {
            dout.writeUTF(point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
            Log.v("write", point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
        }
        dout.flush(); // Flush stream ...
        dout.close(); // ... and close.
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (isMapReady==true){
        try {
            FileInputStream input = openFileInput("latlngpoints.txt");
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
            int sz = din.readInt(); // Read line count
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                String str = din.readUTF();
                Log.v("read", str);
                String[] stringArray = str.split(",");
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[1]);
                listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            }
            din.close();
            loadMarkers(listOfPoints);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList("places",  listOfPoints);
}
private void restore(Bundle outState){
    if (outState != null) {
        listOfPoints =(ArrayList<LatLng>)outState.getSerializable("places");
    }
}
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
    restore(outState);
}
private void loadMarkers(List<LatLng> listOfPoints) {
    int i=listOfPoints.size();
    while(i>0){
        i--;
        double Lat=listOfPoints.get(i).latitude;
        double Lon=listOfPoints.get(i).longitude;
        MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

        mp.position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon));

        mp.title("my previous position");

        mMap.addMarker(mp);

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(Lat, Lon), 16));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are really close to getting this.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430559/how-to-make-a-search-on-google-maps-for-finding-hospitals-etc/33431118#33431118

Comment: Glancing through your code it looks like you are doing all the right things to save and load markers. One thing that is interesting is if (isMapReady==true)
Now is this condition not true whenever onResume happens? It may be that the map is just not ready by the time onResume happens. Could you verify this?

Comment: @CrashOverride That part of the app is working now. Now I am facing issue that when the app is being destroyed and started again, it is not showing previously saved markers. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

- The `getLastLocation()` method might return a null value if no previous location is available: [getLastLocation Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient))
- The last know location isn't necessarily your current location
- `super.onStart()`, `super.onPause()` and `super.onStop()` should be the first instructions in your `onStart()`, `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods. [More infos about Activity Lifecycle and methods overriding](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

In the `onPause()` method you save in your file the Locations contained in the `listOfPoints` but you never add the last known location to that list. You probably want to add that in the `onConnect()` method.

**EDIT**: When you start the app, `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods are invoked ([see Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)). Which means, the `addMarker()` method will likely be called when the map is not ready yet. You might want to add the markers only if the `onMapReady()` method was invoked before.

**EDIT** (since you updated the code):

- Use `openFileOutput("latlngpoints.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND)` instead of `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`
- You should read markers from file also in `onMapReady()` or in `onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)` exactly like you do in `onResume()` method (because when you run the app the map won't be ready yet and you won't execute anything but the if statement in your `onResume()`)

Also notice that your file will likely containt duplicates

Comment: I modified my code to include these lines in onConnect() method:
        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        listOfPoints.add(newLatLng);
But now when I try to run the code it gives me error "unable to resume activity because attempt to invoke virtual method addMarkers in loadMarkers code has been made".

Comment: Can you please suggest the way to do it?

Comment: @AkhilAgarwal you can use an `isMapReady` boolean attribute (`false` as default) and set it as `true` in the `onMapReady()` method. Then you should update the map in the `onResume()` method only if `isMapReady` is `true`. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_map_code if you didn't set the `onMapReady()` callback yet

Comment: Now my app is running but still it is not showing me previous position markers. Everytime I open the app it shows marker only at my current location.

Comment: @AkhilAgarwal can you please post your updated code?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am able to load previous markers as long as I am stopping the app but not destroying it. But when I close the app(destroy it), it is not able to load the previously saved markers. Please suggest what can I do to solve this.